# Open all excel file from folder based on cell reference-excel vba

Tags: hyperlink, reference, cell

I have a following macro which used to open all files based on the value in the cell reference. I am not sure why the below macro is not working.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim UserSelectedFile As Variant
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFile As String
        strFolder = Sheets("Snapshot").Range("a12").Value
        strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xlsm*")
        Do While strFile <> ""
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & strFile)
            strFile = Dir
        Loop
End Sub
```

I need to open all the .xlsm files in readonly mode based on link given in cell A12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a string missing in your declaration.

```
Sub MacroTest()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim FileName As String
Dim UserSelectedFile As Variant
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFile As String
        FileName = Sheets("Snapshot").Range("A12").Value
        strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xlsm*")
        Do While strFile <> ""
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & strFile, ReadOnly:=True)
            strFile = Dir
            DoEvents
        Loop
  End Sub
```

Comment: It is not working could you plese check.